# Basic JOGL program java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to start using [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) to display some 2D graphics. I've written using openGL before (in C) but I'm using the code found [here](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials%3aJava%3aLWJGL%3aIntroduction) just to learn how to make it work. I import the .jar's and the program compiles fine but I get the runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.opengl.Display
at Game.cleanup(Game.java:105)
at Game.main(Game.java:40)
```

If I comment that line I just get a ClassLoader somewhere else but still with the Display class. I've tried various configurations of the .jar locations etc. but nothing seems to resolve this.

I'm using Eclipse Helios on Mac OS 10.6.6

Comment: Turns out I just wasn't adding the native library location to the imported .jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not linking the jar files to the native binaries. I just added that and it worked fine.